# How to choose the right Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, aspnetcore-environment

I'm using AspNet Core identity for the authentication of my users. I want to connect to remote identity providers (Microsoft and Google). For Google, I think I'm fine with using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.google).

For Micorosft I have a couple of options, though:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect

I was first using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD. Then I switched to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount. I was assuming that this would not have much impact but it turned out that now all name-identifiers of my users have changed. So, appearantly there *are* differences.

I find it not very clear what the pros and cons of the different options are. Can someone help me make a good choice?

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount**

This namespace contains types that enable support for Microsoft Account OAuth based    authentication.
It Enables  users to sign in with their existing credentials:

**1)Is convenient for the users.**

**2)Shifts many of the complexities of managing the sign-in process onto a third party.**

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-5.0%5D)

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect**

This namespace contains types that enable support for OpenIdConnect based authentication.And OpenID Connect is an identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows clients to request and receive information about authenticated sessions and end-users.

If you need to add authentication to an application and you want to use a third party as the authentication provider, then the recommended way to achieve this is using OpenId Connect.

Like Google or Facebook, OneLogin is also an [OpenId Connect provider](https://www.onelogin.com/pages/openid-connect), which means that if you use OneLogin to store and manage the identities of your users, you can also use OneLogin to authenticate those users on your custom built apps.

For more details refer this [document](https://developers.onelogin.com/blog/how-to-use-openid-connect-authentication-with-dotnet-core)

**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD**

The libraries **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD** packages. As Per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/authentication-aad-packages-obsolete), since ASP.NET core 5.0, users should use the **Microsoft.Identity.Web package** to integrate with Azure AD and Azure ADB2C.

To migrate from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD to  Microsoft.Identity.Web refer this [document](https://www.taithienbo.com/migrating-from-microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-azuread-to-microsoft-identity-web-authentication-library-to-integrate-with-azure-ad/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed overview. I'm still a bit puzzled though. In AspDotNet Core Identity I read about using external identity providers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social) using the methods AddGoogle, AddFaceBook. AddMicrosoftAccount. What would be the use case of using OpenIdConnect here (how does it compare to the AddGoogle, AddFaceBook, ... methods)? Ans similar, why would I use Microsoft.Identity.Web when I can also connect to Azure AD with AddMicrosoftAccount. You see, I am still concerned that I'm missing something.